# Copy permissions from one user to another user - SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, moss, wss

I want to copy the permissions of a user and to another user. I know i can do it by creating a group with required permissions and adding the users will do it. But i dont want to create a group. Is there a way to copy the permissions of a user to another user directly?

NLV

Comment: Copy permissions of a user using C# code? SharePoint API or web services? I think some more details are needed...

Comment: of course through C#. I've tagged it as C# :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write code that will;

1. Check if the current site inherits permissions or sets its own
2. From the site that sets permissions (self or ancestor, depending on 1) go over the RoleAssignments collections
3. For each role assignment check if your source user is specified
4. If so, create a role assignment for the target user

This code must run under administrative privileges (RunWithElevatedPrivilegese will suffice if written as web part)

Comment: Can a single user/group have multiple RoleAssignments?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to copy permissions between users through SharePoint itself, you will have to write a script to do it for you.

Comment: What script? Can you explain?

Answer (score -1):

There is no OOTB way to clone SharePoint user permissions. You should either use 3rd party tools such as ShareGate, Axceler ControlPont, Boost Solutions's Permission manager or Use this PowerShell script way: Copy Permissions from One User to Another in SharePoint using PowerShell

[Copy Permissions from One User to Another in SharePoint using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/clone-sharepoint-user-permissions-using-powershell.html)